# Spring Boot Kubernetes startup speed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

Looking for recommendations on improving Spring Boot startup speeds on Kubernetes. We're running a REST API built on Spring Boot on a relatively low amount of resources (obviously I'm aware I can throw more compute at the problem, but I want to optimise other aspects first).

One of the major sticking points is the fact that dispatcherServlet only initialises after the first HTTP request is received. Can this be started up before this.

Additionally, how can I eagerly establish the connection to our JPA Datasource (in this circumstance, a MySQL server)

Lastly, we use JobRunr as a background job processor. Can this be abstracted to a different container within the pod, or a different pod altogether?

This is our Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade --available
RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk17-jre-headless
RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY target/app.jar /opt/app
CMD ["java", "-Xmx400m", "-jar", "/opt/app/app.jar"]
```

Tips/Tricks/Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Look at k8s startupProbe, readinessProbe and livenessProbe and Spring Actuators. Here you can check the resource (your servlet) and also the database connection. These should be standard checks before registering your container with the service.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to, [Spring Boot Common Properties] [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.web]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.web%5D)

spring.mvc.servlet.load-on-startup = 1

Comment: This was a big help thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to achieve small memory footprint and super fast startup times - I would recommend you to take a loot at [GraalVM Spring project](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html).

Your program will use AOT compilation, which means that your compilation\build time will be increased, but your startup time will be decreased drastically.
Small screenshot from comparison of 2 different aproaches
[image]

---

But also you have to understand that removing JIT will remove code warmups that is done periodically.